# Converting this format to a json string

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to dynamically add some data to a dictionary in python which I then convert to a json formatted string.

```
{
  "Module": "lights",
  {
    "id": 1,
    "power": 50
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "power": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "power": 25
  }
}
```

the id and power need to be added dynamically how would I achieve this with python? How would I read the same json format as well?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking, or what you've tried. Maybe check out the guidelines? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Data can be added to the dictionary just like you would to any other. You can read and write JSON files with Python's [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module.

Comment: that's an invalid construct in both json and python

Comment: The `id/power` dicts need to be put into a list, and that list should be the value of a key in the outer dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's an invalid construct in both JSON and Python
it should be something like

```
{
  "Module": "lights",
  "Values":[
      {
        "id": 1,
        "power": 50
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "power": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "power": 25
      }
  ]
}
```

grouping all the dicts {_id: ..., power: ...} in a list

taken care of that, converting from JSON to dict and vice-versa one could use the `load/loads` and `dump/dumps` methods from the `json` or `simplejson` packages